`exec` is accessing local variables
I'm learning about bash and zsh. One command I came across was exec. I know that it will replace the current process with the supplied command. By what I have read over the internet, the local variables will not be inherited in the replaced process of exec. I tested it and failed. I am using zsh 5.9 on MacOS 14.
Here is what I wrote,
> a=2
> exec echo $a
2

process exited...

I thought it might be due to parameter expansion and I tried the following
> a=2
> exec echo '$a'
$a

process exited...

Since it printed $a, I'm guessing that parameter expansion didn't happen. Otherwise, the single quotes would have been removed and $a would have been treated as an expansion instead of a string.
To further verify if the variable was inherited or not, I used the declare command. The output is as follows
> aa=2
> exec declare -p | grep aa
typeset aa=2

Even this shows the local variable.
Since exec doesn't inherit the local variables, why is it happening? I don't think it is only related to zsh.

I can't reproduce it. With my bash (5.2), exec echo '$a', prints a literal $a  and then brings me back to the parent shell. Same with zsh (5.8.1).

Hey @user1934428, my shell prints $a as well. I have two doubts. First, like eval echo '$a' prints the value of a, shouldn't exec echo '$a' also look for variable a? Also, as declare command is printing the variable name, does the variable really exist in the replaced process as well?

I don't see at which point the variable should be evaluated. Imagine that you run a program foo by doing exec foo '$bar'. The shell of course does not evaluate the variable bar, but it sets up the execution of foo, passing to it the string $bar in its ARGV[1]. foo is then doing with this string what it wants to do. Similarily echo is just performing its duty and writes the string to stdout, followed by a newline.

exec declare -p does not work in bash. I think bash can't exec, if the "program" to run is an internal command. In zsh, it works. My impression is that zsh, recognizing that declare is internal, just reuses its current shell, executes the declare (which then shows the local variable, since it is the same process), and terminates: zz=888; exec declare -p shows the value for zz.

Isn't echo a built-in as well?

But there is in addition a /bin/echo, while there can't be a /bin/declare. I guess bash and zsh both run the /bin/echo, when they exec.

Yes, that's what exec does: it looks for an executable file, and executes it. Functions and built-ins are excluded (though not in zsh), rather than taking precedence over path lookup.

Yes, $a is expanded first, then exec receives the arguments echo and 2.
With single quotes, exec receives the arguments echo and $a.
In bash, exec declare -p should fail, as declare is a shell built-in command, not an executable.
In zsh, using the built-in declare does not cause exec to fail, but is executed in the current shell, and then the current shell exits. (Because you used a pipeline, though, the current shell is a subshell that "copied" the parent, and that's what exits.) You can consider that inheritance if you like, but it's special zsh behavior, not related to the POSIX definition of exec.

From man zshbuiltins:

exec [ -cl ] [ -a argv0 ] [ command [ arg ... ] ]
Replace the current shell with command rather than forking.  If command is a shell builtin command or a shell function,
the shell executes it, and exits when the command is complete.


Hey, echo is also a builtin. So did it also execute in the current shell? Also, could you provide any reference for what you said regarding declare being executed in the current shell?

@Dhruv: See my other comment for echo. For the current zsh running declare, this simply follows from the fact that the local variables survive the exec.

The shell can (and probably did) find /bin/echo (or similar), so executed that in place of the built-in. declare is only  a built-in (built-in by necessity, rather than for efficiency).

It's not so much about the locals surviving the exec, as being copied over in preperation for the exec. exec doesn't know or care that the shell that executes it isn't the shell that started the pipeline.

Is any reference available for this special behaviour of running builtins in the same environment? Just looking for confirmation

I just ran exec eval echo '$a' and it printed nothing. eval is a builtin without any path, so it should be run in the same environment, right? So, why wasn't 2 printed?

Yes, in the description of exec in man zshbuiltins.

"... and it printed nothing". Did you define a value for a? a=3; exec eval echo '$a' outputs 3 (then exits) as expected.

Sorry for the silly mistake. The value wasn't declared. Thanks for your great explanation.
